# How to reduce the radius/size of the circular button?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to create a circular button in flutter.

I achived that through  :

```
 RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: ()
                    {

                    },

                    shape: CircleBorder( ),
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                 )
```

But the size of the button is too big for use , i want to reduce the radius of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your desired value instead of 15 in below code snippet.

```
RawMaterialButton(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 15, minHeight: 15),
                onPressed: () {},
                shape: CircleBorder(),
                fillColor: Colors.white,
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `constraints` property for the `RawMaterialButton` to change the size.

> **constraints property**
>
> BoxConstraints constraints final
>
> Defines the button's size.
>
> *Typically used to constrain the button's minimum size.*